# My Content is not in the Content Div. It Goes Under The footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-position

I dont know why but, my content div has all of its "content" under the footer,in an empty html area. The shell of the div is there but not what is inside. Any Answers?

Here's the link: http://minecraftserverzz.com/youtube/hai/

[image: -----------]

[image: ----------------]

[image]

[image]

```
#Content {
    width: 60%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.flex {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}

#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #1f3952;
    z-index: -1;
}
footer {width: 100%;}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #001a33;
    display: flex;
}

#footer .nav {
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
}

#footer .nav h1 {
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#footer .nav2 {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
}


#footer .nav2 h1 {
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

### ------------------------------------------------------

Comment: When i use position: absolute on the content div, it works. But the footer is blocking it.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your content div, there is an extra div contentpages with max height.
Please remove that.

Comment: Omg, i didn't even notice that was interfering with it. there was no purpose of that being there anyway :p Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a clear element to the footer? It should look like this:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #001a33;
    display: flex;
    clear: both;
}
```

Let me know if this helps!